# Validação de Login Java

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, login, javafx

Estou precisando de uma ajuda com relação a um trabalho da faculdade, em que preciso fazer uma validação de Login. A aplicação é em Java, interface JavaFX, usando o banco MySQL. A minha dificuldade é entender como buscar e comparar o que o usuário digitar com as informações do banco. Segue o código atual abaixo:

**LOGIN CONTROLLER**

```
package application.controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class LoginController {
    
    private AnchorPane rootLayout;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNomeUsuario;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtSenha;
    @FXML
    private Button btnEntrar;
    
    
    @FXML
    private void logar(ActionEvent event) {
        
        String nomeUsuarioLogin = txtNomeUsuario.getText();
        String senhaUsuarioLogin = txtSenha.getText();
        
        //Aqui eu não sei o que fazer

    }
    
    
}
```

**CONNECTION BASE**

```
package application.models.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionBase {
    
    protected Connection conexao;
    
    public Connection open() {
        
        try {
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver Ok");
            
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pi_grupo6", "root", "ROOT");
            
            System.out.println("conexão ok");
            return conexao;
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public void close() {
        try {
                if(conexao != null)
                    conexao.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


}
```

**TELA JAVAFX**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="415.0" prefWidth="476.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controllers.LoginController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="220.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="196.0" text="Senha">
         <font>
            <Font size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txtNomeUsuario" layoutX="46.0" layoutY="164.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="385.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <Button fx:id="btnEntrar" layoutX="188.0" layoutY="336.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="Entrar">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <PasswordField fx:id="txtSenha" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="252.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="382.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </PasswordField>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="132.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="196.0" text="Nome de Usuário">
         <font>
            <Font size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="86.0" prefWidth="460.0" text="Sistema de Controle de Contas" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Quem puder ajudar, muito obrigada desde já :)